# Number circle with gaps

Tags: mathematics, puzzle-identification, missing-digits

Does anyone know what this is and how to solve it?

Thank you.

[image: 1.]
[image: 2.]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the Puzzling SE! If the puzzle you posted is not of your own making, you need to explicitly state where the puzzle is from. (Looks like it's from some sort of IQ test, or possibly some other similar quiz.)

Comment: Hi, It is part of an entrance Maths exam past paper for Secondary school. I have googled the image and searched for similar puzzles with no luck. There is only this as a guide and I don't have the answers to be able to work it out. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the name of the entrance math exam? Or even the name for the secondary school? There might be similar problems among the others in the guide.

Comment: Is that two different puzzles or do they work together ?

Comment: It is Xenion maths exam and there is only a printed book that you get when you enter. Instructions are in Greek and translate to "Fill in the missing" There is no other problem like this, the rest is basic maths, fractions and graphs. Unrelated.

Comment: http://www.xenion.ac.cy/admin/uploads/pdfs/pdf156.pdf, page 44

Comment: Since this is from a math exam, would this be better fit to be asked on the Mathematics Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this has puzzled me for a while. I have a partial answer based on some assumptions. This test is designed for primary school children, looking at the rest of the paper everything is basic so this puzzle should be the same. I think we are supposed to ignore the bottom horizontal line and instead picture the shape in 8 equal slices. I think the two missing numbers of the left hand shape clockwise from top are 8 and 36. I've tried to draw this out:
--------------64-----2
-----------36/32----------4
-----------16----------6
--------------4------8
My logic is that either the opposite number is the square/square root OR the right hand side is the two times table and the left hand side is 4*1, 4*4, 4*8 , 4*12.

Assuming the right hand one is a separate puzzle I think the missing numbers clockwise from top are 8 and 19. The right hand side being adding 1 then 2 then 3 and the left hand side being adding 3*1, 3*3, 3*4. The last one's a stretch but its the best I could come up with.

Comment: 36 should be 32, no?

Comment: Good point, changed answer as I'm not sure which fits best

Comment: I wonder whether that bottom horizontal line is just a *mistake* and is meant to be a SW-to-NE diagonal line.

Comment: Assuming the odd lines are indeed a mistake, the first circle looks like the pairs ought to be x & 3x+1

Comment: Note in particular that if you flip the right-hand end of that bottom horizontal line about the obvious horizontal axis, the new line goes neatly through the centre of the circle.